# jQuery - Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am so confused...I was working on my site and added some jQuery. Upon testing, I found that the jQuery didn't do anything. I then tried the most simple yet visible code I could think of:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("html").click(function() {
    $("html").html("");
  });
</script>
```

but that didn't do anything either. So I tried that same code in the js console and got back this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
  at <anonymous>:2:1
  at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:848:140)
  at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:891:34)
  at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:627:21)
```

and just entering `$` just gives back "undefined".

I investigated and found that I had accidentally moved my Gemfile, and that maybe the server couldn't access the `jquery-rails` gem. But after I moved it back and restarted the server, the problem didn't go away.

Then I thought maybe I had some faulty code on my page that was preventing the jQuery from running. I removed all the code so it was a just a blank document, ran it, and tried again, but I got the same errors in the console.

The `head` of my app includes this:

```
<head>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
</head>
```

My `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` includes the line `//= require jquery`

And `bundle install` returns "jquery-rails 4.1.1".

I've ran plenty of jQuery before on the same page with no issues. It seems my server suddenly just stopped understanding jQuery. What on earth could be going on?

Comment: What's the code in question? You seem to have included everything else, so you might as well do the whole shebang.

Comment: If you are running spring sometimes it keeps your server running. Try `bin/spring stop` and then restart your server.

Comment: @PetrGazarov I am running spring but unfortunately I tried what you said and nothing changed.

Comment: @MarsAtomic No code works, but I added the particular code I discovered this error with.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Wrap it in a jQuery function, like this:

```
// Note the "$" inside function() - that's the key
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {

  $("html").click(function() {
     $("html").html("");
  });

});
```

Comment: Um...yeah, now it works. What on earth happened?? My other jQuery was working no problem like a day ago.

Comment: It's a race condition issue. You were calling `$` before it was loaded by page. In the above sample, the code within the function of the body is only executed once the page is finished loading.

Comment: That working for my stuff, but other wordpress's plugin doesn't work anymore... 
Even if i do it on a specific script js or after my html ... :/
I can't know why. If someone has any ideas ;)
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include jquery in `app/assets/application.js`:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Comment: Oh yeah, it's included.

Comment: And you're seeing the content from the <application.js> tag load on your page when you view the page in development? Any errors in the console?

Comment: What do you mean? If I view my page's source code I should expect to see "//= require jquery" somewhere on it?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was trying to use an HTML element with my code block for a specific page in WordPress. However, this caused a "$ is undefined" error because jQuery wasn't fully loaded yet. To resolve this, I moved the code block to the header section, where it works just fine.